# Failing to run a file through its pathway in the Linux terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, raspberry-pi3

Hi so I am trying to run my file by typing down the whole pathway of my Login.sh file because I want to run my program automatically upon bootup of my Raspberry Pi. 
The pathway for my Login.sh file is:

```
/home/pi/Desktop/RPI_code/Logger_v1_01/Login.sh
```

So my Login.sh file is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn sudo openconnect vpn.ucr.edu/engineering 
expect -r "\[sudo] .*\: " {
       send "pw_for_my_linux\n"
}

expect "Username:" {
       send "my_vpn_username\n"
}

expect "Password:" {
       send "vpn_password\n"
}
spawn sudo python logger.py
expect -r "\[sudo\] .*\: " {
       send "pw_for_my_linux\n"
}  

interact`
```

this program works fine when I run it from the terminal under the folder Logger_v1_01. But when I run it from the terminal under /home with the files pathway it gives me the following error:

```
python: can't open file 'logger.py':[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Anyone can help explain why this is the case? Why can't I open a file which clearly exists?

Answer (score 0):

When you run `python logger.py` you're using a relative path for `logger.py`.  So if it's not in the current directory it won't be found.  You could either use an absolute path and be able to run it from anywhere, or you could do something within the script to ensure it's local, like always doing a `cd` to the directory containing it.